# nginx: how to always redirect to different host when we redirect

Tags: nginx

The title is a bit misleading, but I can't think of a better one.

I'm hosting an nginx server behind CloudFront. The nginx server can be accessed at `origin.website.com` which is the origin for CloudFront. The CloudFront distribution is hosted at `website.com`.

Is there a way to make it so that, every time we redirect, we redirect to `website.com/$uri` rather than `origin.website.com/$uri`?

I'm trying to cover all my bases, but I do have a specific problem:

```
server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  origin.website.com website.com;
        add_header X-server-choice "default";
        add_header X-heard-uri "$uri";

        root /var/www;
        client_max_body_size 200M;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
        location /blog {
                alias /var/www/blog;
                index index.php;
                try_files $uri $uri/ @site_rewrite;
        }

        location @site_rewrite {
                rewrite ^/blog/(.*)$ /blog/index.php?$1;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/$fastcgi_script_name;
                include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny  all;
        }

}
```

Whenever I go to `website.com/blog` it redirects to `origin.website.com/blog/`. It seems to be going through `location /blog` and redirecting in the `try_files $uri $uri/ @site_rewrite` without going through the `site_rewrite`.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Is `website.com` ClodFront's distribution CNAME?

Comment: @DmitryMiksIr Yes. Most of the time it works. It's only on website.com/blog that it messes up

Comment: Well, I think this redirect generated by your php blog.

Comment: @DmitryMiksIr oh that's really smart I didn't think of that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you could put a full url for the rewrite target, ie

```
rewrite ^/blog/(.*)$ $scheme://website.com/blog/index.php?$1 redirect;
```

Comment: Yes, this is all good and well, but I believe the rewrite is actually occurring in the `try_files`, as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: for further evidence, I tried this and it did not work

Comment: That means its matching on $uri or $uri/. You can alternatively put a separate server block as such:

`server {
listen 80;
server_name origin.website.com;

return 301 $scheme://website.com$request_uri
}
`
which will redirect all of origin.website.com to website.com. You would have to remove origin.website.com from the server_name in the server block you pasted above.

Comment: That would cause a redirect loop because CloudFront asks the server for `origin.website.com` rather than `website.com`. I just want it to redirect to `website.com` only when it was going to redirect anyways.